# How to setup a predicate based on the count of one of the to many attributes

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am writing an iPhone app.  In my app, I have an Entity in my database ( let's call it MusicCategory) that has a to-many relation ship with another entity (lets call it Songs) in my database.

I am trying to write a query to get the 5 MusicCategories that have the most number of songs.

can some one please give me some pointers as to how I can write the predicate for this query ????

thanks a lot for your help
Vijay

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Hi Tim, I don't know where to start. I read the apple code data documentation and searched the web but couldn't find any  help. Right now, I am getting all the items in the Music Category entity and am programatically finding the top 5. As a programmer, my gut says that there should be a way using the predicates.

Answer (score 1):

The approach with sorting is the right one. You can limit your fetch request to the 5 top ones you need:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:
   [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"songs.count" 
                                descending:YES]];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using some predicates you just need to set a sort descriptor that sorts by the number of songs. But that is not efficient, because it would fire faults. So you could add a **count** attribute to make it more efficient.

```
request.sortDescriptors =[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"songs.count" ascending:YES]];
```